# How do you debug a regex?

Tags: regex, debugging, pcre

Regular expressions can become quite complex.  The lack of white space makes them difficult to read.  I can't step though a regular expression with a debugger.  So how do experts debug complex regular expressions?

Comment: I believe that "testing" your regex is much more important than "debugging" it. You can usually figure what's going on with a regex quite easily looking at the result (or using one of the tools suggested in the answers), but to be really sure it does what you mean you should test your regex with all possible border cases. Testing will eventually clarify what really you want to do and make the debugging useless :)

Comment: This seems interesting: [http://www.debuggex.com/](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28%3F%21%5E%28PRN%7CAUX%7CCLOCK%5C%24%7CNUL%7CCON%7CCOM%5Cd%7CLPT%5Cd%7C%5C..%2A%29%28%5C..%2B%29%3F%24%29%5B%5E%5Cx00-%5Cx1f%5C%5C%3F%2A%3A%5C%22%3B%7C%2F%5D%2B%24&str=.dotfile-not-valid)  (Since question is closed I cannot add a real answer.)

Comment: If you have Visual Studio, you can set a breakpoint near your problem area (eg: `RegEx.Replace(...)`, switch to 'Immediate window' and try out a few `'Regex.IsMatch(yourDebugInputString, yourDebugInputRegEx)` commands to quickly zero in the issue.

Comment: I'm very surprised nobody seems to have mentioned https://regex101.com/ which has an _actual_ debugger and is web-hosted as well.

Comment: even in 2017, I believe regexbuddy is still the best tool I can find, and the price remains at $40. I often work at different languages with different regex flavour, so I often get confused. With regexbuddy, it just frees me from the syntax

Comment: Try CodVerter regex tester: https://codverter.com/src/regextester Online regex tester to validate regular expression patterns. Editor is updating while typing and flags can be changed as desired.
Work can be saved local or to the cloud.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You buy [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) and use its built in [debug feature](http://www.regexbuddy.com/debug.html). If you work with regexes more than twice a  year, you will make this money back in time saved in no time. RegexBuddy will also help you to create simple and complex regular expressions, and even generate the code for you in a variety of languages.

[image]

Also, according to the developer, this tool runs nearly flawlessly on [Linux when used with WINE](http://www.regexbuddy.com/wine.html).

Comment: Too bad it's Windows-only and costs US$40.

Comment: It runs on Linux via WINE, according to the developer: http://www.regexbuddy.com/wine.html. And about the $40 cost...how much is your time worth?

Comment: @KeynnyTM It works under wine, and I get paid to write code so this saves money.

Comment: This is not free software.

Comment: Who said it was or asked for it?

Comment: @Tim: I don't know about others, but it definitely prevents *me* from using it.  One of my primary development platforms is a PowerPC Linux machine.

Comment: Well, like Mick said, how much is your time worth? "The best tools money can buy" don't always have to cost money, but sometimes they do. Plus, JGSoft consistently develops *great* quality products with exceptional user service. I have even bought software from them I don't really need (like RegexMagic) because I'd like to support them and keep them in business. You don't know what you're missing. Seriously.

Comment: +1 My only complaint is that it does not (yet) handle `(?R)` recursive expressions. Otherwise, as Tim says, the quality of all JGsoft software (and the support backing it up) is nothing short of _Excellent!_ (spoken with a Monty Burns accent of course!)

Comment: Is that screenshot from Windows 8? I didn't realize it was available back in Feb 2010.

Comment: It's an image linked to the developer's website. They must've updated it.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit late to the party, but I stumbled over this thread and could not help to recommend http://www.regex101.com/. It does not do everything regexbuddy does, but its get damn near close to it.

Comment: But seriously, you do a mofo regex debugger and aim it only at Windows users? How's that even sane? There's also perl's rxrx debugger.

Comment: @VicGoldfeld: I realize I'm bumping an old thread, but you should check out http://regex101.com/ which now offers a debugger. Check out this example: http://i.imgur.com/Ilz80VV.png or http://regex101.com/r/wS5zF2/#debugger. The debugger only runs PCRE right now.

Comment: [regex101](http://regex101.com/) is great all in all a superp service as long as you're writing regular expressions for the three provided flavors. **Unfortunately .net flavor is not part of the list.** So whenever you try to use balanced groups you're toast.

Comment: @kennytm I got this up and running on my MacOS Catalina 10.15.x with no issues by first installing Parallels Desktop, https://www.parallels.com/, and then installing RegexBuddy onto it. Whole process when smooth. Not sure what OS you run, but just FYI. Heck I even paid $70 for Parallels, as I might need to run other Windows apps on my Mac OS. Wine does not run on MacOS Catalina 10.15.x as of right now.

Answer (score 53):

With Perl 5.10, [`use re 'debug';`](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html).  (Or `debugcolor`, but I can't format the output properly on Stack Overflow.)

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'"foobar"=~/(.)\1/'
Compiling REx "(.)\1"
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   REG_ANY (4)
   4: CLOSE1 (6)
   6: REF1 (8)
   8: END (0)
minlen 1
Matching REx "(.)\1" against "foobar"
   0 <> <foobar>             |  1:OPEN1(3)
   0 <> <foobar>             |  3:REG_ANY(4)
   1 <f> <oobar>             |  4:CLOSE1(6)
   1 <f> <oobar>             |  6:REF1(8)
                                  failed...
   1 <f> <oobar>             |  1:OPEN1(3)
   1 <f> <oobar>             |  3:REG_ANY(4)
   2 <fo> <obar>             |  4:CLOSE1(6)
   2 <fo> <obar>             |  6:REF1(8)
   3 <foo> <bar>             |  8:END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "(.)\1"
```

Also, you *can* add whitespace and comments to regexes to make them more readable.  In Perl, this is done with the `/x` modifier.  With `pcre`, there is the `PCRE_EXTENDED` flag.

```
"foobar" =~ /
    (.)  # any character, followed by a
    \1   # repeat of previously matched character
/x;

pcre *pat = pcre_compile("(.)  # any character, followed by a\n"
                         "\\1  # repeat of previously matched character\n",
                         PCRE_EXTENDED,
                         ...);
pcre_exec(pat, NULL, "foobar", ...);
```

Comment: +1: Why would anyone prefer Regexbuddy to this?

Comment: I like this method,  even though i think regex buddy is better.

Comment: echo "foobar" | egrep "(.)\1"

Answer (score 30):

When I get stuck on a regex I usually turn to this:
https://regexr.com/

Its perfect for quickly testing where something is going wrong.

Comment: This tool is really useful: it's web hosted so no installing, it's real time so debugging is a dream, and it even has useful tooltips and a list of special characters, in case you cant remember something. It's perfect, thanks alot

Comment: Unfortunately, this tool (still) does not allow you to change the regex delimiters (even for the PCRE engine) - they are fixed as `/` (slashes). This is a showstopper for me.

Answer (score 30):

I'll add another so that I don't forget it : [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/)

It's good because it's very visual: [image: Photo of the Debuggex regex helper]

Comment: debuggex actually doesn't work for me: the fonts are enforced by JavaScript, apparently, and fail to work (I have monospaced fonts, the firefox console uses them perfectly). As a consequence the display is unusable. In addition, the JavaScript testing hangs the browser with a lot of test cases, for every edition (not only once when fired). Finally, some of the proposed regexes are bugged and do not match as intended.

Answer (score 19):

I use [Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/) - The Python Regular Expression Debugger:

> Kodos is a Python GUI utility for creating, testing and debugging regular expressions for the Python programming language. Kodos should aid any developer to efficiently and effortlessly develop regular expressions in Python. Since Python's implementation of regular expressions is based on the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) standard, Kodos should benefit developers in other programming languages that also adhere to the PCRE standard (Perl, PHP, etc...).
>
> (...)
>
> [image]

Runs on Linux, Unix, Windows, Mac.

Comment: Kodos doesn't provide true debugging features. You can't step the regex nor pause the execution.

Comment: Any tips on getting it working on a Mac?  The Sourceforge site doesn't offer any info on installing for Mac, and my Google-fu seems to be failing me.

Comment: Although this would seem to be Python2, and hasn't been updated since 2006 (14 years ago at the time of writing)?

Answer (score 13):

I think they don't. If your regexp is too complicated, and problematic to the point you need a debugger, you should create a specific parser, or use another method. It will be much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Dude, you posted this after looking at the regexbuddy screen shot?

Comment: Everyone will disagree with this, but it's not a bad idea. Everyone assumes that the regex engine is most efficient with enormous regexes. This is not necessarily true, and they're definitely not easy to read. Break your regexes up.

Comment: @Michael Brooks: No, before, actually. Having seen the screenshot, I'm okay with the fact you CAN debug a regexp. But I stand on my idea : when a regexp becomes too complicated, it's time to change to another way.

Answer (score 12):

There is an excellent free tool, [the Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/).  The latest version is only available for Windows; its author Dr. Edmund Weitz stopped maintaining the Linux version because too few people downloaded it, but there is an older version for Linux on the download page.

Answer (score 9):

I've just seen a presentation of Regexp::Debugger by its creator: Damian Conway.
Very impressive stuff: run inplace or using a command line tool (rxrx), interactively or on a "logged" execution file (stored in JSON), step forward and backward at any point, stop on breakpoints or events, colored output (user configurable), heat maps on regexp and string for optimization, etc...

Available on CPAN for free:
http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Debugger/lib/Regexp/Debugger.pm

Comment: OP said "I can't step though a regular expression with a debugger."

Comment: Do you have a link to the presentation?

Comment: @Rook, You can view the presentation at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcSFIUiMgAs

Answer (score 7):

I use this online tool to debug my regex:

https://www.regextester.com/

But yeah, it can't beat RegexBuddy.

Comment: This would seem to be identical to https://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 7):

As for me I usually use pcretest utility which can dump the byte code of any regex, and usually it is much more easier to read (for me at least). Example:

```
PCRE version 8.30-PT1 2012-01-01

  re> /ab|c[de]/iB
------------------------------------------------------------------
  0   7 Bra
  3  /i ab
  7  38 Alt
 10  /i c
 12     [DEde]
 45  45 Ket
 48     End
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6):

I debug my regexes with my own eyes. That's why I use `/x` modifier, write comments for them and split them in parts. Read Jeffrey Friedl's *[Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/hipowls.html)* to learn how to develop fast and readable regular expressions. Various regex debugging tools just provoke voodoo programming.

Answer (score 4):

I use:

http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

You can also try Regex Hero (uses Silverlight):

http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 3):

If I'm feeling stuck, I like to go backward and generate the regex directly from a sample text using [txt2re](http://www.txt2re.com/) (although I usually end up tweaking the resulting regex by hand).

Answer (score 3):

If you're a Mac user, I just came across this one:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/reginald-regex-explorer/

It's free, and simple to use, and it's been a great help for me to get to grips with RegExs in general.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the (non-free) [tools on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html). [RegexBuddy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy.html) in particular. [Here is Jeff Atwood's post on the subject](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Answer (score 2):

Writing reg exes using a notation like PCREs is like writing assembler: it's fine if you can just see the corresponding finite state automata in your head, but it can get difficult to maintain very quickly.

The reasons for not using a debugger are much the same as for not using a debugger with a programming language: you can fix local mistakes, but they won't help you solve the design problems that led you to make the local mistakes in the first place.

The more reflective way is to use data representations to generate regexps in your programming language, and have appropriate abstractions to build them.  [Olin Shiver's introduction to his scheme regexp notation](http://www.scsh.net/docu/post/sre.html) gives an excellent overview of the issues faced in designing these data representations.

Comment: Parser combinators are indeed an awesome way to go: Parsec and PArrows in Haskell, rsec in Ruby, Boost Spirit in C++, PyParsing in Python, Perl6::Rules in Perl, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I often use pcretest - hardly a "debugger" but it works over a text-only SSH connection and parses exactly the regex dialect I need: my (C++) code links to libpcre, so there's no difficulty with subtle differences in what's magic and what isn't, etc.

In general I agree with the guy above to whom needing a regex debugger is a code smell.  For me the hardest about using regexes is usually not the regex itself, but the multiple layers of quoting needed to make them work.

Answer (score 2):

I often use Ruby based regexp tester [Rubular](http://rubular.com)

and also in Emacs use <kbd>M-x</kbd> [re-builder](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReBuilder)

Firefox also has a [useful extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2077/)

Answer (score 2):

I use the Rx Toolkit included with [ActiveState Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one
http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Answer (score 0):

For me, after having eyeballed the regex (as I'm fairly fluent, and nearly always use /x or equivalent), I might debug rather than test if I am unsure if I would hit some degenerate matching (i.e. something that excessively backtracks) to see if I could solve such issues by modifying the greedyness of an operator for example.

To do that, I'd use one of the methods mentioned above: pcretest, RegexBuddy (if my current workplace has licensed it) or similar, and sometimes I time it in Linqpad if I'm working in C# regexes.

(The perl trick is a new one for me, so will probably add that to my regex toolkit too.)