# Testing regular expressions tool (Linux/ubuntu)

Tags: regex, linux

I searched for a question about regexp testing/learning tools, but people usually suggest Windows based solution. I found one for ubuntu: redit.
However, I'm wondering if there are better tools for the job. So, without further ado

```
Q: What is the best tool for testing/leadning regular expressions
   for linux/ubuntu?
```

Sorry if this is a superuser kind of question.
Thx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I rather like [Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/), which is a cross-platform GUI regex tester.

But there are many others. Have a look at the answers to [How do you debug a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348694/how-do-you-debug-a-regex) , there are many cross-platform solutions listed.

Comment: Kodos is damn old, uses Qt3 and has not been updated since 2006.

Comment: @pouya, you forget the entry was from 2010. Besides, there is an updated version here, still working quite fine: https://github.com/luksan/kodos

Comment: @nyov still the same. The Latest commit is made on 2012. Anyway these days with [electron](https://electronjs.org/) in hand building such a tool takes only half an hour.

Answer (score 13):

Why don't use web-base tools: http://regexpal.com/ and more [here](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_VIVN245&=&q=regex+tester&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: thank you for the answer... i do like to have things downloaded & installer, though.

Comment: I think its better to know you can code even if your net is down.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ Adobe Air app. Worth a try

Answer (score 0):

For simple regex I use the replace function in [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

Answer (score -4):

Best "tool" for learning regex?

Easy: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: This fails to answer the question is akin to a "RTFM" response. The most repugnant form of 'help'.