# How do I build an ICU regex to match this kind of string?

Tags: regex, string

Hi I need an ICU regex that I think it is pretty basic but I don't know how to build it right. The regex should match strings like:

```
font-size: 9pt;
font-size: 15pt;
font-size:2pt;
font-size:22pt;
```

I'm trying to make something like this but it doesn't work:

```
regex = \bfont\-size: [0-9]{3}pt;\b
```

I'm really new to regex so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S.: Does anyone know a good resource to get the hang of this fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font\-size\: ?[0-9]{1,3}pt\;`

Should do the trick. Essentially, escape all non-alphanumeric characters (just to be on the safe side). Also, `{1,3}` means repeating 0-9 from one to three times, instead of always three times.

**Edit:**
Updated the above regex. The trailing `\b` was removed, and the space before the number was made optional using `?`.

**Python demonstration:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """
... font-size: 9pt;
... font-size: 15pt;
... font-size:2pt;
... font-size:22pt;
... """
>>> re.findall("font\-size\: ?[0-9]{1,3}pt\;", s)
['font-size: 9pt;', 'font-size: 15pt;', 'font-size:2pt;', 'font-size:22pt;']
```

Comment: great, thanks! And how do I change this to match this kind of strings but with decimal numbers? e.g. font-size: 9.5pt; I tried: font\-size\: ?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]+)?pt\;  and it doesn't work. It is so frustrating...

Comment: A very simple approach would be `font\-size\: ?[0-9\.]{1,3}pt\;`, but it would also match stuff like 9.5.2pt. (**EDIT:** Actually it won't match 9.5.2 as it only matches 3 characters, heh.) There's nothing wrong with your regex, perhaps you're using it wrongly.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! You are right I was using it wrong. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see with your regex:

1. `{3}` matches exactly three things. You probably want `{1,3}` to match 1 to 3.
2. I don't think `\b` is going to do what you want right after a semicolon. Perhaps you want something like `\s*` (zero or more whitespace).

If you want to learn regexes fast, your best bet might be to use a [regex debugging tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348694/how-do-you-debug-a-regex) and experiment.