# java regex stays processing but no result is thrown

Tags: java, regex

so im learning regex in java  and  was  wondering  why  when  i execute this code

```
String xxx = "(\\s+)?(c:/|c:\\\\|C:\\\\|C:/|c:\\|C:\\))?(\\w+(/|\\\\)?)+(/|\\\\)\\w+.[a-z]+";

String x = "C:\\Users\\esteban\\Desktop\\Java_file_testing\\file3.txt";

    if(x.matches(xxx)) {
        System.out.println("matches");
    }else {

            System.out.println("no match found ");
    }
```

this prints `matches` but  when  i remove  the   `.txt`  is  stays processing  without any response,  am i doing something wrong?

Comment: so when it doesnt have .txt is it matches or not matches?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin "stays processing without any response" = "`x.matches(xxx)` doesn't return"

Comment: @immibis what I want to know is the expected result. Yes I am aware of it.

Comment: expected result should  be  `no match found`  if i remove the .txt

Comment: you need to escape the `.` before `[a-z]+`

Comment: @Avinash Raj,  even if i add the `\\.`  instead of `.` the result is the same :   it stays  processing  without any result  when i remove the `.txt`   OR  just  the `txt`  and leave the period ( . )

Comment: This question seems related: [Infinite loop in regex in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500507/infinite-loop-in-regex-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex is using dot `.` character that matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

You have to escape the dot as:

```
(\\s+)?(c:/|c:\\\\|C:\\\\|C:/|c:\\|C:\\))?(\\w+(/|\\\\)?)+(/|\\\\)\\w+\\.[a-z]+
                                                          here --------^
```

Btw, you can shorten your regex like this:

```
\s*[Cc]:(?:(?:\/|\\{1,2})\w+)+\.\w+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wG4rV0/2)**

Remember to escape backslashes:

```
\\s*[Cc]:(?:(?:\\/|\\\\{1,2})\\w+)+\\.\\w+
```

Comment: Hello.
1. I  escaped the dot  but the loop still keeps on taying there processing.
2.when i  use this regex  `\\s*c:(?:[\\/\\]{1,2}\\w+)+\\.\\w+`  it throws  an exception : 
` Unclosed character class near index 27
\s*c:(?:[\/\]{1,2}\w+)+\.\w+ `

Comment: @user3710334 Have you tried with the second regex I posted?

Comment: @user3710334 You have to escape the regex as this: `\\s*[Cc]:(?:(?:\\/|\\\\{1,2})\\w+)+\\.\\w+`

Comment: ok   and  this doesn't throw exception but it never matches 
`\\s*c:(?:[\\/\\\\]{1,2}\\w+)+\\.\\w+`<<  never matches 
`\\s*c:(?:[\\/\\]{1,2}\\w+)+\\.\\w+` << exception

Comment: FYI `/` isn't a delimiter here, so there's no need to escape it.

Answer (score 3):

You stumbled upon a case of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) !

When you write `(\\w+(/|\\\\)?)+`, you are basically introducing the `(\\w+)+` pattern into your regex. This leaves the opportunity for the regex engine to match a same string in multiple ways (either using the inner or the outer `+`) - the number of possible paths increases exponentially, and since the engine has to try all possible ways of matching before declaring failure it takes forever to return a value.

Also, a few general comments on your regex:

- `c:\\|` will match, literally, the string `c:|`
- `/|\\\\` is just `[/\\\\]`
- `(\s+)?` is `\s*`
- `.` is a wildcard ("anything but a newline") that need to be escaped
- for the `c`/`C` variations, either use `[cC]` or make your whole regex [case insensitive](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-how-case-insensitive-search-string-matches-method)
- when you don't need to actually capture values, using non-capturing groups `(?:...)` relieves the engine of some work

Taking these into account, a regex in the spirit of your first attempt could be:

```
\\s*(?:[cC]:[/\\\\])?(?:\\w+[/\\\\])*\\w+\\.[a-z]+
```

In `(?:\\w+[/\\\\])`, the character class `[/\\\\]` isn't optional any more, thus avoiding the `(\\w+)+` pattern: see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/xX1pA0/1).

For more information on catastrophic backtracking, I'd recommend the excellent (and fun !) article by Friedl on the subject on [the perl journal](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol1_2/tpj0102-0006.html).