# checking a password for upper lower numbers and symbols

Tags: php, regex

I am using the below script to check my passwords for length, uppercase, lowercase and numbers.

How could I change it to make it check FOR symbols instead of against symbols?

```
<?php

    $password = 'afsd323A';
    if( 
        //I want to change this first line so that I am also checking for at least 1 symbol.
            ctype_alnum($password) // numbers & digits only 
        && strlen($password)>6 // at least 7 chars 
        && strlen($password)<21 // at most 20 chars 
        && preg_match('`[A-Z]`',$password) // at least one upper case 
        && preg_match('`[a-z]`',$password) // at least one lower case 
        && preg_match('`[0-9]`',$password) // at least one digit 
        )
    { 
        echo 'valid';

    }
    else
    { 
        echo 'not valid';// not valid 
    }     
?>
```

Comment: You are checking *for* characters. Can you clarify what you want to do instead?

Comment: so you want the password to contain at least one symbol as well?

Comment: Right Jacob. Upper Lower Numbers and Characters

Comment: Well, the first line is checking for "numbers & digits only", I'd start by removing that...

Comment: The problem with using all those function in an if statement, is you are traversing the string at least 4 times, maybe 6 (depending on if php stores the string length).

Answer (score 9):

your desired regex is below

```
   $pattern = ' ^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$ ';

   preg_match($pattern,$password);
```

### [DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/hpDwhMCTCX)

Comment: Please try to google... here it is [Reference](http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/)

Comment: I optimized a bit
`((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{7,21})   - 27 steps` ; `your - in 50 steps; `

Comment: @Dmitrij how do u find the steps?? any website?? please refer

Comment: I am using RegexBuddy (powerfull and chip tool). Example of debugging you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348694/how-do-you-debug-a-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Either you determine a list of valid symbols:

```
preg_match('`[\$\*\.,+\-=@]`',$password)
```

or you can look for anything that isn't alnum:

```
preg_match('`[^0-9a-zA-Z]`',$password)
```

Comment: Except that OP wants the password to contain at least one of each. At least one upper, one lower, one digit, and one symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Tests if the input consists of 6 or more ASCII characters.The input must contain at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit.

```
if(preg_match('/\A(?=[\x20-\x7E]*?[A-Z])(?=[\x20-\x7E]*?[a-z])(?=[\x20-\x7E]*?[0-9])[\x20-\x7E]{6,}\z/' $password))
    echo("valid password");
```

Comment: To check if it contains non-alphanumeric characters try this regular expressions: `if(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $password) echo('Password contains non-alphanumeric characters');`

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this , working.

```
$pattern = '/^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+`~\[\]{}?])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,30}$/';
preg_match($pattern,$password);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it