# How to determine where a regex failed to match using Java APIs

Tags: java, regex

I have tests where I validate the output with a regex.  When it fails it reports that output X did not match regex Y.

I would like to add some indication of where in the string the match failed.  E.g. what is the farthest the matcher got in the string before backtracking.  `Matcher.hitEnd()` is one case of what I'm looking for, but I want something more general.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: This is probably your best bet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348694/how-do-you-debug-a-regex

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo: Thanks, Perl's "use re 'debug'" is close to what I'm looking for.  Something similar that is callable from Java would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a match fails, then `Match.hitEnd()` tells you whether a longer string could have matched. In addition, you can specify a region in the input sequence that will be searched to find a match. So if you have a string that cannot be matched, you can test its prefixes to see where the match fails:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LastMatch {
    private static int indexOfLastMatch(Pattern pattern, String input) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        for (int i = input.length(); i > 0; --i) {
            Matcher region = matcher.region(0, i);
            if (region.matches() || region.hitEnd()) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-z]+");
        String[] samples = {
                "*ABC",
                "A1b*",
                "AB12uv",
                "AB12uv*",
                "ABCDabc",
                "ABC123X"
        };

        for (String sample : samples) {
            int lastMatch = indexOfLastMatch(pattern, sample);
            System.out.println(sample + ": last match at " + lastMatch);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this class is:

```
*ABC: last match at 0
A1b*: last match at 3
AB12uv: last match at 6
AB12uv*: last match at 6
ABCDabc: last match at 4
ABC123X: last match at 6
```

Comment: This is good, though I find the second case confusing.  The entire string matches, so why report 4?  I suggest:
`region.matches(); if (region.hitEnd()) ...`.  Then it returns 6 for that case.

Comment: Good catch. I only tested for partial matches and didn't take into account full matches of the complete string or any of its prefixes. This is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the string, and iterate over it, removing one more char from its end at every iteration, and then check for `hitEnd()`:

```
int farthestPoint(Pattern pattern, String input) {
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input.substring(0, i));
        if (!matcher.matches() && matcher.hitEnd()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: intput.length()

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pair of `replaceAll()` calls to indicate the positive and negative matches of the input string.  Let's say, for example, you want to validate a hex string; the following will indicate the valid and invalid characters of the input string.

```
String regex = "[0-9A-F]"
String input = "J900ZZAAFZ99X"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex)
Matcher m = p.matcher(input)
String mask = m.replaceAll('+').replaceAll('[^+]', '-')
System.out.println(input)
System.out.println(mask)
```

This would print the following, with a `+` under valid characters and a `-` under invalid characters.

```
J900ZZAAFZ99X
-+++--+++-++-
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it outside of the code, I use [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) to test the regex expressions before sticking them in the code.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this tells me if text doesn't match a regex, but it doesn't tell me where it fails to match.  That's what I'm looking for.