# Java-specific regular expression testing program

Tags: java, regex, windows, testing

I'm looking for a regular expression testing program that I had installed on my previous workstation that I am now unable to find anywhere.

It was for java-specific regex's, so I'm pretty sure it was written in Java. There were a few tabs across the top, one of which was the explanation of the different regex terms from the Pattern class in the API.

The top text box was for entering text, the middle text box was for the regex, the bottom text box was where the matches were displayed.

I know that it's not much to go on, but does anyone recognise it?

Comment: Don't recognize it, but it seems like a simply enough program to write yourself real quick.

Comment: I don't recognise it, but you could try this online java regex checker while you search for the program: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

RegexSR

http://cui.unige.ch/~deriazm/apps/regexsr/

Comment: the website provided leads to a malicios content warning (http://regexsr.oxgva.com/install.exe)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any specific desktop program that does it, but I personally am using [this website](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) which offers most of the stuff you're looking for (apart from the explanations).

I'd at least give it a look - great program in my opinion. Offers all the important flags, several different strings to test and prints out the java string of the given RE (so not manually inserting \ wherever it's necessary!)

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be Java-specific, use [Regex Coach](http://the-regex-coach.en.softonic.com/). I use it for Java expressions and haven't run into a problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). It supports [Java](http://www.regexbuddy.com/screen.html). You can find screenshots [here](http://www.regexbuddy.com/screen.html).

You can see this [StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348694/how-do-you-debug-a-regex) for more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I use [RegExr](http://regexr.com/), JavaScript based.

Comment: Looks quite nice. I'll have to try it out.

Comment: The download shows some virus/advare. Won´t use it

Comment: Also, does not seem to support Java

Comment: Actually, it's ActionScript based (an ECMAScript implementation from Adobe, with a few additional features).  The offline version uses Adobe Air.  I've been using it for years, and just now updated it; there are no ads or viruses in it.

Comment: RegExr is fine--awesome, actually--until you need to do lookbehind, which works in Java but apparently not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try Kodos regex tester (for windows), a good regex tool. I have used them initially to test regex patterns and used them in Java.

http://kodos.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion http://regex101.com is by far the best online regex checker for various regex formats, including Java Regex
which You asked for. It even lets you debug all the steps (including forward and backward lookup) and explains the terms of the regex you develop!

Comment: I do not find the java testing there