# Checking for inefficient regexes

Tags: ruby, regex

- How can I check whether a Ruby 2.0 onigmo (or 1.9 oniguruma) regex includes inefficiency such as catastrophic backtracking?
- How can I follow the internal steps that a Ruby 2.0 or (1.9) regex match is attempted against a string?

Comment: What is up with the close votes for the question "not being about programming"??? How could a question be *more* closely related to programming than this?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are allowing users of your app to do regex searches on data, and want to prevent DOS attacks from malicious users. If that is the case, an alternate solution would be to run each regex search in a separate thread, and kill threads which take too long to finish.

Comment: @AlexD Thanks for the comment, but the regexes are actually written by  me. It is used to analyze a DSL, and it is very complicated. For example, it includes recursive reference to match balanced parentheses. Shamefully, I cannot fully check my own regexes whether they are effective or not.

Comment: @sawa: insofar as I was reading earlier today, the gist of avoiding catastrophic backtracking is to avoid `(expression*)*` and variations thereof. If you that sort of thing, you probably have backtracking problems -- any possibility to match a set of characters with two cases or more in your regex is potentially problematic, because it'll end up being explored. (Good question, btw. I wish this kind of stuff wasn't deemed off topic on SO...)

Comment: @AlexD, maybe because the question uses the phrase `Is there a tool`. It could be changed to `How can I` to become more `"on-topic"`. Anyways, +1 on the question, I've voted for reopen.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I will change the question a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Regexbuddy, according to this page, allows to detect them:

> Regexbuddy is forgiving in that it detects it's going in circles, and aborts the match attempt. Other regex engines (like .NET) will keep going forever, while others will crash with a stack overflow (like Perl, before version 5.10).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

(Not sure how up to date the info is)

Also found this related question:

[How do you debug a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348694/how-do-you-debug-a-regex)

In the case of ruby, there also seems to be additional compile flags that you can enable:

> recompiled Ruby 2.0 (ruby-head) from source after setting a couple of special compiler flags: `ONIG_DEBUG_COMPILE` and `ONIG_DEBUG_MATCH`

http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/4/3/exploring-rubys-regular-expression-algorithm

Comment: Note that regexbuddy doesn't support possessive quantifiers in ruby mode.

Comment: RegexBuddy just tries to perform a match on a whatever string you feed it, and if it hasn't gotten a result after an arbitrary number of operations, it quits.  Then you can switch to Debug mode and see exactly what it was doing.  It works great, but I think he wants a tool that can analyze the regex alone and warn you if it *could* result in never-ending matches.