# RegEx pattern for a price

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This mightbe a silly question, but I'm new to RegExes.
I need a RegEx pattern for a price in my python program.

Sample cases :

```
8.00
25.14
271.61
2,367.82
52,124.09
9,37,159.82
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think your last example is formatted badly.  A comma should be followed by three digits, you have `9,37,159.82`

Comment: Yes, but amazon.in uses the same kind of pricing pattern and my program scrapes data from amazon.in .

Comment: Please do some research about regexes before you ask a question. If you still didn't succeed, then show what you tried in your question.

Comment: @kaveman: If there is a problem with a post, please describe the problem in detail, instead of just posting "what have you tried". See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134) on whether "what have you tried" comments are acceptable and alternatives to "what have you tried". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one matches all of the above:

```
(\d{1,3},?)*\d{1,3}\.\d{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match numbers formatted according to the rules of [Indian numbering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system). In order to do this correctly you have to carefully define what you would like to treat as a match. For example would string such as `100,10,100.00` constitute a match? You can find a validly formatted number inside this example, i.e. `10,100.00` but I assume that for your purposes string from the example should not match. I elaborated a bit on the tests and came up with this test suite:

```
# match
8.00
25.14
271.61
2,367.82
52,124.09
9,37,159.82

# don't match
9,378,159.82
9,37,159.820
12,.80
12,12
12.,12
12,12.80
10,80
.80
80,
```

Following regular expression passes these tests successfully.

```
(?<![\d,])((\d{1,2},)*\d{3}|(\d{1,3}))\.\d{2}(?!\d)
```

Comment: Why would: 9,37,159.82 match?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't quite understand your question, but I'll try to interpret it to the best of my ability. 9,37,159.82 is a properly formatted number accorting to Indian numbering system. Explaining why supplied regular expression matches this particular number, that is writing a step-by-step execution of regex, would be too long for the comment. If you're interested in understanding which steps regex engine will take I suggest using a debugging tool. You can find different options to debug a regex in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348694/how-do-you-debug-a-regex

Comment: Never seen a price that uses commas after 1 then 2 numbers - that's all. Prices are typically $100,000.00 or something like that. OP didn't mention Indian Numbering system, but I'm not familiar with that either.