# how to enable traces for Boost Regex and Boost Spirit Lex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-regex

How can I enable debugging traces for those libraries such as the traces created by Boost Spirit Qi.
It would be useful to get some generated XML files which show me the paths of the underlying states.

Comment: I think you know what you're looking for. It would be nice to just link to an example of what you meant, instead of "sketching a  feature request" as if you just invented it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Boost Regex has this. See [How do you debug a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2348694/85371)

For Boost Spirit you can define

```
  #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
  #define BOOST_SPIRIT_LEXERTL_DEBUG
```

and a similar one for Lex. The output for Lex is not XML, as I remember, but it does name the state transitions and (obviously) recognized token IDs.

For an example of [how to use `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES` see one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES)

See also

- Debugging (http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/debugging/)

Comment: Do I have to use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES for the token_def attributes like I did for the Qi rules?

Comment: Not AFAIR. But I'd hunt down a sample that uses this to be sure